# How to append results from a repeated function?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, repeat

I have a function that repeats a function until a certain value has been reached.
For each repetition, a variable X changes and so should the result Y. I want to save every value that X and Y take as a dataframe.

```
get_Y <- function(X) {
  Y <- Xˆ2
}

get_dataframe <- function() {
  X <- 1
  repeat {
    get_Y(X)
    X <- X*1.01
    if (X > 2)
      break
  }
}
```

How do I save each X and Y to a dataframe, where each row is an iteration?

Comment: Do you want to do it efficiently in a typical R style that looks very different from where you're at now, or do you want to do it with minimal modifications to your existing code but very inefficiently?

Comment: @GregorThomas Always open to improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty efficient answer. The efficiency gains over your set up come in 2 main ways: (1) pre-calculate the length of the result so we can optimally (2) take advantage of the fact that `get_Y` is vectorized, so we can call it on the entire input at once rather than one item at a time.

```
get_Y <- function(X) {
  Y <- X^2
}

get_dataframe <- function() {
  n = ceiling(log(2) /  log(1.01))
  X = cumprod(rep(1.01, n))
  data.frame(X, Y = get_Y(X))
}

get_dataframe()
#           X        Y
# 1  1.010000 1.020100
# 2  1.020100 1.040604
# 3  1.030301 1.061520
# 4  1.040604 1.082857
# 5  1.051010 1.104622
# 6  1.061520 1.126825
# 7  1.072135 1.149474
# ...
# 65 1.909366 3.645680
# 66 1.928460 3.718959
# 67 1.947745 3.793710
# 68 1.967222 3.869963
# 69 1.986894 3.947749
# 70 2.006763 4.027099
```

Comment: This definitely answers my question. But it also gave me a new one for you. Now what if get_Y does multiple things and defines multiple variables and eventually does the Y <- ... ? Do I just use return then to avoid that Y = get_Y(X) makes Y have a vector of all the defined variables?

Comment: R functions should return 1 object. (They can't return more.) If you need to include multiple values in the returned object, then you can put them in a vector if they are the same class, or if they are different classes you can have them returned in a `list`. You can handle vector or list returns to get the output however you want.

Comment: Ah so I assume that if you do not use the return command, it returns the last object you defined? Like in this case, Y.

Comment: Yes, the last line of the function will be returned. In my answer, `get_Y` returns `Y` and `get_dataframe` returns the data frame because those are on the last lines of each function.

Comment: It works in my model! My last question is, what if the starting value of X is not 1.01? But still has to be multiplied repeatedly by 1.01?

Comment: `starting_value * cumprod(rep(1.01, n))`. You might want to make the first one `1`, i.e., `cumprod(c(1, rep(1.01, n - 1)))`. And you may have to be more careful calculating the length of the sequence. `start * 1.01^n = end` take the log `log(start) + n * log(1.01) = log(end)` solve for `n`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253885/discussion-between-victor-nielsen-and-gregor-thomas).